# How to remove " no duplicate" records from a row, in my-sql

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates, having

For example, If I have

```
+------------+-------------+
| something_1| something_2 |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | a           |
| 2          | b           |
| 3          | a           |
| 4          | c           |
| 5          | b           |
| 6          | a           |
| 6          | d           |
| 6          | e           |
+------------+-------------+
```

I want this, deleting the no-duplicates data:

```
+-------------+
| something_2 |
+-------------+
| a           |
| b           |    
+-------------+
```

Thanks, I want it in mysql, please

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. What is considered a duplicate for you? You want to delete what? The second table is the result or what you want to delete?

Comment: @WalterMacambira he wants to keep only rows which has duplicate row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you only the duplicate fields:

```
SELECT something_2 FROM mytable
GROUP BY something_2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have a primary key for your table, do the following:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE prim_key IN (SELECT prim_key FROM my_table
GROUP BY something_2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```